# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo , android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, facebook

i am getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fb.test/com.fb.test.Fb_testActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020005 error
```

i am just putting following code by creating android project

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class Fb_testActivity extends Activity {    
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("318494558191146");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace? Try cleaning your project and running the app once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if R.layout.main exists or not.

Comment: main.xml , string.xml all files are available

Comment: have you copied all resources from sdk to your project resources

Comment: here i have  importd whole android-sdk as library into project so  i didnt made any changes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your application supports multiples languages, and some strings are missing in one of the strings.xml files ?